# Error in requireNamespaceQuietStop("e1071") : package e1071 is required

Tags: r, plyr, r-caret

```
> traceback()
9: stop(paste("package", package, "is required"))
8: requireNamespaceQuietStop("e1071")
7: postResample(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"])
6: ctrl$summaryFunction(testOutput, lev, method)
5: evalSummaryFunction(y, wts = weights, ctrl = trControl, lev = classLevels, 
       metric = metric, method = method)
4: train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...)
3: train(x, y, weights = w, ...)
2: train.formula(classe ~ ., data = train[1:10, ], method = "gbm", 
       trControl = trainCtrl)
1: train(classe ~ ., data = train[1:10, ], method = "gbm", trControl = trainCtrl)
> ?postResample
```

---

I am using the caret package. Getting error when using train function

```
trainCtrl = trainControl(method='cv', p=1, number=2)
model = train(classe ~ ., data=train[1:10,], method="gbm", trControl=trainCtrl)
```

> Error in requireNamespaceQuietStop("e1071") : package e1071 is
>   required

I can install and library() the e1071 package, but I don't know why I have to do that and if it indicates some deeper problem. I wiped out my entire R installation and reinstalled it, but did not fix.

---

**OS: Mac Yosemite 10.10.4**

**R Version: 3.2.1_1**

**Caret Version: 6.0-52**

**RStudio Version 0.99.467**

Comment: caret doesn't depend on e1071 meaning that it wont load when you load caret, so you will still need to load e1071 on its own, is that what you're asking?

Comment: I don't understand. Does the error goes away after you install `e1071` or does it still persist? The `caret` library depends on functions from other packages depending on which `method=` you choose.